# How to check if one string's characters exist and are in the same position as those in another string?

Tags: python

I have a list containing the characters of this string:

> wordtoguess = ['T', 'R', 'A', 'N', 'S', 'M', 'I', 'S', 'S', 'I', 'O', 'N']

And I have the user guess a word and store it in the variable 'guessed'. I also have a variable called 'correct_chars' which is equal to 0.

> guessed = input()
>
> correct_chars = 0

When the user guesses a word I want Python to iterate through each character of the word and if it exists and is in the same place as the corresponding character in wordtoguess, to add 1 to correct_chars. For example if the user inputted the string 'translations', then correct_chars would be equal to 5. I have been unable to figure out how to do this so far.

Comment: Can you post ideas on how you think this might be done?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potential implementation:

```
>>> wordtoguess = "TRANSMISSION"
>>> guessed = "TRANSLATIONS"
>>> correct_chars = sum(1 for (x, y) in zip(wordtoguess, guessed) if x.lower() == y.lower())
>>> correct_chars
5
```

Comment: You can also sum bools directly: `sum(x.lower() == y.lower() for x,y in zip(wordtoguess, guessed))`. I find this reads very closely to the English "go over the corresponding characters in each string and add up how many match".

Answer (score 0):

```
guessed = input()

correct_chars = 0
wordtoguess = ['T', 'R', 'A', 'N', 'S', 'M', 'I', 'S', 'S', 'I', 'O', 'N']

for i, c in enumerate(guessed):
    try:
        if c.upper() == wordtoguess[i]:
            correct_chars += 1
    except IndexError:
        pass

print(correct_chars)
```

Comment: Once you have an IndexError, the rest will be IndexError as well, so you could break instead of pass there. You could also use zip instead of dealing with indices for the same effect (it stops after its shortest argument is exhausted).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution

```
guessed = input()

correct_chars = 0
wordtoguess = ['T', 'R', 'A', 'N', 'S', 'M', 'I', 'S', 'S', 'I', 'O', 'N']

for i in range( len(wordtoguess) ):
    if i >= len(guessed):
        break
    if wordtoguess[i] == guessed[i]:
        correct_chars = 0
```